# Change WooCommerce shipping classes displayed order

Tags: wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, settings

After I added shipping classes manually in order from the highest price (300) to the lowest price (80), it seems that it doesn't work out in the desired order. Does anyone know how to fix this?
Desired order:$80, $90, $200, $300

[image: ScreenShot]

I tried to upload shipping class one after the other in order from the highest price to the lowest, so that their order would be accordingly, but it did not happen as expected, the order of the prices changed regardless of the shipping prices

Comment: When I change the slug it does not affect the order.
But when I change the shipping class and add 0, it does change properly.
But I don't want to call the shipping class that way in the system, because I have a lot of shipping classes it could create disorder

Comment: Then it seems that shipping classes are sorted by their names, so you have no other choice to rename "$80" and "$90" to "$080" and "$090"…